# How to wait X second to finish rolling update in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, rolling-updates

I am using k8s to deploy my docker apps.

Once app is stated it took 20-30s to be ready, app is huge it took some time while booting.

Boot average time is 20-30s. I would like to wait for 60s during the rolling update. Because for now, old pod is terminated while booting new app (in new pod).

How can I do it?

Comment: Have you [configured a readiness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) for your pod?  The old pod shouldn't get torn down until the new pod is ready (and the probe passes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure [readiness probe and startup probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) in the pod spec with a `failureThreshold * periodSeconds` long enough to cover the worse case startup time.As an example.

```
ports:
- name: readiness-port
  containerPort: 8080
  hostPort: 8080

readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /healthz
    port: readiness-port
  failureThreshold: 1
  periodSeconds: 10

startupProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /healthz
    port: readiness-port
  failureThreshold: 30
  periodSeconds: 10
```

Comment: Ok. so `/healthz` is some endpoint from my app and its called every 10second (and it will fail in 30) when response code is 200 its signal for k8s that my app is ready?